# databinding of object property in dictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have question about databinding in XAML. I have dictionary in which are my objects. Now in the view I want show in first listbox key of dictionary (with this no problem), but in nested listbox show values of that object.

So - my code in XAML:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Dict}" Margin="0,0,171,0">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
             <StackPanel>
                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Key}" />
                 <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Value}">
                     <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                         <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Key}" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value}" /> <!-- HERE -->
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

following with code from ViewModel:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    t = new TestModel();
    t._dict = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, myDrive>>();

    t._dict.Add("folder1", new Dictionary<string, myDrive>());
    t._dict["folder1"].Add("file1", new myDrive() { size = "71" });
    t._dict.Add("folder2", new Dictionary<string, test>());
    t._dict["folder2"].Add("file1", new myDrive() { size = "54" });
    t._dict["folder2"].Add("file2", new myDrive() { size = "30" });

    this.DataContext = t;
}
```

and code from model:

```
public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, myDrive>> _dict;

public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, myDrive>> Dict
{
    get
    {
        return this._dict;
    }
}
```

and class myDrive is simple:

```
public class myDrive
{
    public string size = "";

    public string getSize()
    {
        return this.size;
    }
}
```

My goal is show parameter size in that textbox so I tried different ways like:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value.size}" />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value[size]}" />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value.getSize}" />
```

but no luck :(. Only if I put Value like in example, than can see output string : "AppName.myDrive".

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First define property for size variable. You can only Databind properties not variables.

```
public class myDrive
{
    public string size = "";

    public string Size{get{return size;}}
    public string getSize()
    {
        return this.size;
    }
}
```

Once this is done, you can bind like below

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Dict}" Margin="0,0,171,0">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
             <StackPanel>
                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Key}" />
                 <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Value}">
                     <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                         <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Key}" />
                                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value.Size}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Yes, functional now :) Thanks